# Inputting Excel file into Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime, file-io, matrix

I wanted to create a matrix with relevant information from an excel file in Matlab, however, when I read in the excel using:

```
data = xlsread(FILENAME);
```

My values for the "dates" are converted to `NaN`

Sample input excel file:

- [Cell A1] = 12/20/2010
- [Cell A2] = 2/20/2011
- [Cell A3] = 25

However, when I read this into the variable using:

```
data = xlsread(FILENAME);
```

My values in the matrix are:

```
NaN NaN 25
```

Is there a way to change this? I Need the dates.

```
Values in raw:

Cell 1         Cell 2       Cell 3   Cell 4       Cell 5
'Date'        'Expiration' 'Strike' 'Implied Vol' 'Days'
'01/31/2012'  '02/03/2012'  21       .672          3 
'02/1/2012'   '02/03/2012'  21       .231          2
[...]          [...]        [..]     [...]         [...] //1000 more values
```

Comment: What MATLAB version are you running? you might want to know that there was recently a change in functionality: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/xlsread-functionality-change-in-r2012a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the raw data from file, then parse it yourself:

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('file.xlsx');
dt = datenum(raw(1:2), 'mm/dd/yyyy');    %# serial date number
val = raw{3};                            %# double value
```

You can now format the dates as string:

```
>> datestr(dt)
ans =
20-Dec-2010
20-Feb-2011
```

Comment: I get an error with DATENUM failed. Error using dtstr2dtnummx

Comment: I have made an attempt to show whats in raw in the original question (at the bottom)

Comment: @Josh: my code was meant for the small sample you first posted. You need to adjust the indexing to get the dates from each column. For example for the first try `col = raw(2:end,1);`, then parse it as before. The same for the second column

Comment: What about datenum()? I'm still getting an error: DATENUM failed.

Comment: @Josh: difficult to tell without seeing the actual data. It would help if you share the excel file

Comment: The link allows me to only share internet links